# PHP XML manager/Xquery creator?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, rss, xsd

i'm looking for a **PHP solution** to easily traverse (readonly) XML files (rss feeds) from websites. Other providers have XML feeds with different markups and I want to have an easy PHP (possible self-built) manager to just enter an URI and then immediately be able to 'select' nodes/attributes/nodegroups to create somesort of definition for that provider.

Or am I just trying to create XSD files?

I'm not very sure on where to go, other suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: I'm actually looking for somesort of javascript / PHP loader for RSSed XML files from where I can 'select' parts of the XML file with javascript and then generate a XPath query which I can use in PHP. Is this possible? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS is nasty and unless you are absolutely sure that you're only feeding the app well-formed RSS, using PHPs XML parsers will fail at some point.

I've used a simple class originally developed for parsing HTML called [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). The API is easy and handles all kinds of bad markup. As with most other markup parsers, the memory footprint is quite huge.

Comment: I'm indeed finding problems using the default PHP parser. I will be using different feeds from different providers. Provider 1 for instance has 2 feeds providing profile/status information with one, and images with the other (http://tinyurl.com/sorsssample-statusfeed, http://tinyurl.com/sorsssample-imagesfeed). But provider 2 for instance has 1 feed providing all the info (http://tinyurl.com/sorsssample-bothfeed). Also, sometimes data is as nodeValue, sometimes as attribute. Sometimes even the node tagname... Will this all work out?

Comment: I found SimpleXML very ease to handle actually :). Thanks for the answer though